Continuous mapping for $P$ convergence
I have the following problem: Let $X_n \xrightarrow{P} X$ and $Y_n \xrightarrow{P} Y$. Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous. Prove that $f(X_n, Y_n) \xrightarrow{P} f(X,Y)$.
My proof currently:

We want to show that for $\forall > 0: \lim_{n \to \infty} P(\vert f(X_n, Y_n)-f(X,Y)\vert > \epsilon)=0$. By the continuity of $f$ for $\forall \epsilon > 0$ there $\exists \delta > 0$ such that $\Vert(x,y)-(u,v)\Vert < \delta \Longrightarrow \vert f(x,y)-f(u,v)\vert < \epsilon$. As we want to control the event $|f(X_n, Y_n)-f(X,Y)| > \epsilon$ we can write based on the previous that $$|f(X_n, Y_n)-f(X,Y)| > \epsilon \Longrightarrow \Vert(X_n,Y_n)-(X,Y)\Vert \geq \delta.$$ Hence, $$P(|f(X_n, Y_n)-f(X,Y)| > \epsilon) \leq P(\Vert(X_n,Y_n)-(X,Y)\Vert \geq \delta).$$ Using the definition of the norm we obtain $$P(\Vert(X_n,Y_n)-(X,Y)\Vert \geq \delta)=P\bigl(\sqrt{(X_n-X)^2-(Y_n-Y)^2} \geq \delta \bigl) \leq P(\vert X_n-X\vert \geq \delta/2)+P(\vert Y_n-Y\vert \geq \delta/2).$$ Since $X_n \xrightarrow{P} X$ and $Y_n \xrightarrow{P} Y$ then by definition $$\lim_{n \to \infty} P(\Vert f(X_n, Y_n)-f(X,Y)\Vert \geq \delta)=0.$$ Finally putting it together we get $$\lim_{n \to \infty}P(|f(X_n, Y_n)-f(X,Y)| > \epsilon) \leq \lim_{n \to \infty} P(\Vert f(X_n, Y_n)-f(X,Y)\Vert \geq \delta)=0.$$ Since $\epsilon$ was arbitrary, this proves $f(X_n, Y_n) \xrightarrow{P} f(X,Y)$.

Does this proof seem sensible? I'm not quite sure about the inequality after "Hence," and also does the inequality after the definition of the norm holds?

Looks like you are tacitly assuming uniform continuity? The standard proof of continuous mapping for $P$ conv. uses the characterisation with subsequences converging a.s.

Thank you! I provided an answer to this question using subsequences.

As mentioned in the comment, this proof makes no sense because it assumes uniform continuity of $f$.
Here is a much easier approach. Let subsequence $\{n_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ be given. Choose subsubsequence $\{n_{k_l}\}_{l=1}^{\infty}$ such that both $X_{n_{k_l}} \to X$ and $Y_{n_{k_l}} \to Y$ almost surely as $l \to \infty$. Therefore, $f(X_{n_{k_l}}, Y_{n_{k_l}}) \to f(X,Y)$ almost surely as $l \to \infty$, which completes the proof.

Thank you! I provided an answer to this question with the correct proof.

Yeah, your own answer is correct. I only corrected "almost every $\omega \in \Omega$".

As my initially provided proof assumed uniform continuity which was not given in the problem I will provide a proof using subsequences which user 温泽海 provided as the answer to the initial question.

Since $X_n \xrightarrow{P} X$, any subsequence $\{X_{n_k}\}$ has a subsequence $\{X_{n_{k_l}}\}$ so that $X_{n_{k_l}} \rightarrow X$ a.s $(l \rightarrow \infty)$. From that same index set $\{n_{k_l}\}_{l=1}^{\infty}$ we can choose subsequence $\{Y_{n_{k_l}}\}$ such that $Y_{n_{k_l}} \rightarrow Y$ a.s $(l \rightarrow \infty)$. Thus we have $$\lim_{l \to \infty} X_{n_{k_l}}(\omega)=X(\omega) \quad \text{and} \quad \lim_{l \to \infty} Y_{n_{k_l}}(\omega)=Y(\omega) \quad \forall \omega \in \Omega.$$ For almost every $\omega \in \Omega$ because $f$ is continuous, we know that $$\lim_{l \to \infty} (X_{n_{k_l}}(\omega),Y_{n_{k_l}}(\omega)) = (X(\omega), Y(\omega)) \Rightarrow \lim_{l \to \infty} f(X_{n_{k_l}}(\omega),Y_{n_{k_l}}(\omega)) = f(X(\omega), Y(\omega)).$$ Hence, we obtain $f(X_{n_{k_l}}, Y_{n_{k_l}}) \rightarrow f(X,Y)$ almost surely as $l \rightarrow \infty$.

